# How can I access parent and sub directory using same domain with .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I have a situation where I want to deploy two projects on same domain.

For example:

```
https://www.myproject.com 
https://www.myproject.com/admin
```

I have all files for first project inside public_html folder, and for second project I have created directory called **admin** under public_html folder.

My .htaccess file looks like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myproject.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(/admin)$ https://www.myproject.com/admin/$1 [R,L]
```

However I am not able to access admin url. Is there any problem in my .htaccess file?

Comment: There is no need to create .htaccess for this I am assuming you had defined your document root properly and have directory index set, then just access them normally it will work.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar I have set my document root properly and also seted my directory index but I am not able to see admin page when using url **/admin** . It shows me normal root page.